# Unicode encoding for Polish characters in Python

Tags: python, unicode

I am having a Polish artist name as follows:

```
Żółte słonie
```

In my dataset (json file), it has been encoded as:

```
\u017b\u00f3\u0142te S\u0142onie
```

I am reading the json and doing some pre-processing and writing the output to a text file. I get the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u017b' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

I looked up the Unicode encoding for Polish characters online and the encoding looks fine to me. Since I have never worked with anything other than LATIN before, I wanted to confirm this with the SO community. If the encoding is right, then why is Python not handling it?

Thanks,
TM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made simple test with Python 2.7 and it seems that `json` changes type of object from `str` to `unicode`. So you have to `encode()` such string before writing it to text file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import json

s = 'Żółte słonie'
print(type(s))
print(repr(s))
sd = json.dumps(s)
print(repr(sd))
s2 = json.loads(sd)
print(type(s2))
print(repr(s2))

f = open('out.txt', 'w')
try:
    f.write(s2)
except UnicodeEncodeError:
    print('UnicodeEncodeError, encoding data...')
    f.write(s2.encode('UTF8'))
    print('data encoded and saved')
f.close()
```

Comment: Thank you...it's in fact the problem with the encoding change by json. Will wait for a few hours and then accept the answer....thank you..

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem, and my solution is a simple change in json.dump method call. I have changed ensure_ascii to False (it is True by default). My method:

```
def save_to_file(self):
    year, month = self.get_month_year_string()
    filename = "./files/project-" + year + "-" + month + ".json"
    with open(filename, "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        # file.write(self.project)
        json.dump(self.project, file, ensure_ascii=False)
```