# How to display polish characters in python

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have in my database varchar column containing text with polish characters.
I already changed format in DB to utf8

Now I am pulling data from DB using Django raw SQL creator and receiving an error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd3 in position 9:
>   invalid continuation byte

I have no idea how to repair it. There is # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- at the beginning of view file.

Will be thankful for each support,

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Are you using python2 or python3 ?

Comment: I am using python 2.7.13

Comment: Try to change into python 3.4

Comment: The whole platform using python 2.7.13, I cannot change it just like that. There is no other solution for this kind of problem in python 2?

Comment: I had the same problem with Greek characters. After changing it from python 2.7 to python 3.4 all problems solved.

Comment: good to know, thanks for this. Anyway I'd like to stay with python 2.7

Comment: You probably need to encode it prior to parse it. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23286663/unicode-encoding-for-polish-characters-in-python) question for example.

Comment: When is this error raised ? When you pull data or when you try to display/edit it ? Please share related code.

Comment: this is raised when I try to display data using return JsonResponse( self.getSqlResult(), safe=False )

Comment: and self.getSqlResult(), returns an array containing objects ( each row is a new object )